# What is the best way to perform an OR condition in SQL

Tags: sql

I have to make a query but I'm looking for a more efficient way to do it using 'OR'.

I am currently doing it as follows.

I wonder if there's a way to not use the field name so many times to make it cleaner.

```
select * from the_table
  where field1 = 23 or
        field1 = 24 or
        field1 = 43 or
        field1 = 4324
```

Comment: [SQL IN Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 3):

That is what the IN clause is for:

```
 select * from the_table
  where field1  in (23,24,43,4324)
```